# Is using route 53 from AWS sufficient for DDOS protection on DNS level, or do you need to combine it with other AWS products

Tags: dns, ddos, aws

We have been targeted by DNS DDOS attacks. We have now migrated to AWS Route53 as these DNS servers are more resilient.

Is using AWS Route 53 enough to have basic DDOS protection? Or is it necessary to combine it with other AWS products like CloudFront/Shield?

Comment: "Necessary" for what? You need to define what level of protection you are looking for or what types of threats you want to counter. Else you will get arbitrary answers, like the one you just got.

Answer (score -1):

Look at AWS Shield. It has free basic DDoS coverage but you have to set it up.

Comment: Are you sure Shield is necessary for route 53? It looks like DDOS protection(on DNS level only) is already included in route 53 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/ddos-event-mitigation-logic-continuous-inspection.html

Comment: We try not to just recommend arbitrary products/services. At least describe how a product/service might solve the OP's problem.